# wazirx api giving 400 error "Request out of receiving window."

Tags: python, rest, request

I want to get user account info using wazirx api the wazirx. I am using python requests for endpoints but I wap `{"code":2098,"message":"Request out of receiving window."}`

how can I fix this error and why I am getting it.

sample requests

```
    ct = datetime.datetime.now()
    ts = ct.timestamp()
    ts = int(ts)
    url = f"https://api.wazirx.com/sapi/v1/funds?timestamp={ts}&signature={secrets_key}"
    

    payload = {}
    headers = {
        'X-Api-Key': api_key,
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    print(response.text)
```

official docs https://docs.wazirx.com/#fund-details-user_data

I am doing something wrong please if anyone ever used wazirx API please guide because the docs are not helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp in sample request is Epoch in milliseconds (`1632377552095`) while `.timestamp()` retuns seconds. Try multiplying it by 1000:
`ts = int(ts*1000)`